# Centos 7: cURL ssl error: you are attempting to import a cert with the same

Tags: ssl, curl, centos7

I am testing a web service protected with mtls. I have issued *both* client and server certificates (for testing purposes) and added the server certificate to trust store.
The following command works on Ubuntu but not on Centos 7:

```
curl --cert MY_CLIENT_CERTIFICATE.pem https://MY_URL
```

On centos 7 (cURL v. 7.29), it returns:

```
cURL error 35: sl error: you are attempting to import a cert with the same issuer/serial as an existing cert
```

Do I understand it correctly that cURL does not allow me to issue both client and server certificates using the same issuer? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating `curl` fixed the problem

Answer (score 1):

> ... cURL does not allow me to issue both client and server certificates using the same issuer

It is not about the same issuer but about the same issuer and serial number:

> ... you are attempting to import a cert with the same issuer/serial as an existing cert

If the same serial number is used for different certificates issued by the same CA then the certificate issuing process is broken: different certificates issued by the same CA MUST have different serial numbers. You need to fix this process and not try to work around it.

Comment: I will check it again but the serial number was different, with only the issuer being the same. I thought it was kind of illegal to issue certificates for both sides.

Comment: The serial numbers are different, it is the issuer that is the same. It still looks like strange behaviour of curl